# How to rectify this exception in c#

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have written the linq query like:

```
    NorthwindContext context = SqlCE;
   var query = context.Destinations.Where(i => i.Id >= 1).Select(i => new {
                    id = i.Id,
                  name = i.Destination
       }).ToArray();

   public NorthwindDataContext SqlCE
    {
        get
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("SQLServerCompactEditionUnderWebHosting", true);
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf";
            return new NorthwindDataContext(connectionString);
        }
    }
```

I have connected to sqlserver northwind.mdf file. I have values in the table also still i am getting null reference exception. How can i rectify this. How to get values in to the query.

Regards

Comment: What is the value of your NorthwindContext? Is it really null as your code example indicates?

Comment: what do you mean by value of NorthwindContext. I am newbie to asp.net mvc.

Comment: In your line of code: `NorthwindContext context = null;` if the context is null, then your `var query` line is like saying `null.Destinations...` so that's where your null reference exception is coming from.

Comment: I have got that thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need something like that:

```
using (var context = new NorthwindContext()) 
{
    var query = context.Destinations.Where(i => i.Id >= 1).Select(i => new {
                id = i.Id,
              name = i.Destination
    }).ToArray();
 }
```

Although there may be more you may be missing (e.g. connection strings, etc).